# Get all Counted ids from count result in MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to get counted ids from count result in mysql

```
ID | version | count
========================
1 |   1.0   |     2
2 |   1.0   |     2
3 |   1.1   |     3
4 |   1.1   |     3
5 |   1.1   |     3
```

For example here i have returned counted version result,what if i want to get ids that are counted by count,simply like(list of ids that are counted),is it possible or any function available in mysql to do this?

I want a result like this

```
Count |counted_ids| version
========================
3     |     1     | 1.0
      |     2     | 1.0
      |     3     | 1.0
```

Comment: Give us the table structure and the query you have used. And also give a sample of the result you are expecting.

Comment: I simply want to get list of counted ids that counted by count function,looking for available function or any way to do so?

Comment: For you it is simple because you know what you want, but for us it is hard to imagine how the result have to look like. So please add a result table to show what you want.

Comment: so many counts...

Comment: I have Edited my query @cdaiga

Comment: Your expected result seems to not base on your sample data?

Comment: its just an example i am trying to let you know how i want the expexted answer

Comment: But your example does not let us know what you really want to do.

Comment: If the Question is solved please mark it as solved, thx.

Answer (score 2):

Please check following query,

```
select version,sum(count) count from table_name group by version
```

Comment: it isn't  giving me the ids that are counted?

Answer (score 2):

Use this statement on the table you posted in your question

```
SELECT `count`, GROUP_CONCAT(`ID`) FROM <your_table> GROUP BY `count`
```

For this Table:

```
ID | version | count
====================
0 |   1.0   |     2
1 |   1.0   |     2
2 |   1.0   |     2
3 |   1.1   |     3
4 |   1.1   |     3
5 |   1.1   |     3
```

It will give you something like this:

```
Count |GROUP_CONCAT(`ID`)|
==========================
3     |      3,4,5       |
2     |      0,1,2       |
```